# Why requests.post have no response with Clustal Omega service?

Tags: python, bioinformatics

```
import requests
MSA_request=""">G1
MGCTLSAEDKAAVERSKMIDRNLREDGEKAAREVKLLLL
>G2
MGCTVSAEDKAAAERSKMIDKNLREDGEKAAREVKLLLL
>G3
MGCTLSAEERAALERSKAIEKNLKEDGISAAKDVKLLLL"""
q={"stype":"protein","sequence":MSA_request,"outfmt":"clustal"}
r=requests.post("http://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/msa/clustalo/",data=q)
```

This is my script, I send this request to website, but the result looks like I did nothing, web service didn't receive my request. This method used to be fine with other website, maybe this page with a pop window to ask cookie agreement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form on the page you are referring to has a separate URL, namely

```
http://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/services/web_clustalo/toolform.ebi
```

you can verify this with a DOM inspector in your browser.
So in order to proceed with `requests`, you need to access the right page

```
r=requests.post("http://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/services/web_clustalo/toolform.ebi",data=q)
```

this will submit a job with your input data, it doesn't return the result directly. To check the results, it's necessary to extract the job ID from the previous response and then generate another request (with no data) to

```
http://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/services/web_clustalo/toolresult.ebi?jobId=...
```

However, you should definitely check whether this programatic access is compatible with the TOS of that website...

Here is an example:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import sys
import time

MSA_request=""">G1
MGCTLSAEDKAAVERSKMIDRNLREDGEKAAREVKLLLL
>G2
MGCTVSAEDKAAAERSKMIDKNLREDGEKAAREVKLLLL
>G3
MGCTLSAEERAALERSKAIEKNLKEDGISAAKDVKLLLL"""
q={"stype":"protein","sequence":MSA_request,"outfmt":"clustal"}

r = requests.post("http://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/services/web_clustalo/toolform.ebi",data = q)
tree = html.fromstring(r.text)
title = tree.xpath('//title/text()')[0]

#check the status and get the job id
status, job_id = map(lambda s: s.strip(), title.split(':', 1))
if status != "Job running":
    sys.exit(1)

#it might take some time for the job to finish
time.sleep(10)

#download the results
r = requests.get("http://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/services/web_clustalo/toolresult.ebi?jobId=%s" % (job_id))

#prints the full response
#print(r.text)

#isolate the alignment block
tree = html.fromstring(r.text)
alignment = tree.xpath('//pre[@id="alignmentContent"]/text()')[0]
print(alignment)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it solved my problem, but how to find the right URL? When I input the right one into my browser, it came to the old wrong one again......

Comment: @NingWang I have included an example - however, there is also an option to install libclustalo locally and use the clustalo package (Python wrapper)

Comment: ,thank you for the detailed answer. If next time, I do another task, how can I know "http://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/services/web_clustalo/toolform.ebi" is the right one, instead of the url I copy from browser?

Comment: @NingWang if you open WebInspector, Firebug or inspect the page source directly, there will be something like `<form action="../../services/web_clustalo/toolform.ebi" ...>` - the form is being submited to the URL specified with the `action` parameter, thus from the original URL you go two directories up and append `services/web_clustalo/toolform.ebi`